# Obstructions to existence of simplicial maps

Tags: reference-request, simplicial-complex

Are there any simple obstructions for the existence of a simplicial map between two given simplicial complexes? A natural candidate would be some simple to compute function that is non-increasing under simplicial maps.

In general I'm interested in finding introductory references that explicitly discuss simplicial maps and their properties.